# Bracha while hiking in a scented forest

Tags: blessing, fruits, trees, besamim-spices

Lets' say one is a hiking in a forest which emits a combination of scents coming from mangoes as well as pine trees or other non-fruit trees. The scents are mixed.

What blessing should one make?

- ".. who gives fruits a good smell"?
- "..who creates 'spice' trees"?
- Both
- Neither

Comment: I honestly would be extremely surprised to find mango trees and pine trees growing naturally in the same forest. Because of this, the first bracha I would say would be Oseh Ma'aseh! :P (This is tongue-in-cheek, btw.)

Comment: @ezra The specific items are examples.

Comment: In all fairness, @Ezra, if it could happen anywhere, it would have to be in Eretz Yisrael... which is why I held my tongue back from making the exact same comment ;)